# How to send latitude and longitude to Meetup API update event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-maps, meetup

I can't seem to get an event to have a location.

I have tried posting data as:

```
{
  'lat,lon': '11.11111,11.11111'
}
```

and

```
{
  lat: '11.11111',
  lon: '11.11111'
}
```

and

```
{
  lat: parseInt(11.1111, 10),
  lon: parseInt(11.1111, 10)
}
```

nothing seems to stick. (the actual values for lat, lon are coming from google maps api, and i've confirmed they are correct)

Specifically, i am using the `meetup-api` [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meetup-api) to make the requests

[meetup api docs / update event](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/event/#edit)

Comment: what does the response show in the network part of the console?

Comment: Well, I'm sending other data, such as the event description and time, and that is working fine. I'm not getting an error.